# Make div have image height while image is loading. (avoid repaint)

Tags: css

Browser firstly is loading div with height 0,
and only after makes height equals image height.
Here are the screen shots : https://puu.sh/vR0Gp/10233ce94d.png

I want to make height as image height from the beginning to avoid repaints. 
Here is the page: http://a4004cc1.ngrok.io/banner1.html

html of the banner:

```
<div class="home-top-box">
    <div class="banner">
        <img src="mobile-main.jpg" width="750" height="500">
    </div>
</div>
```

css of the banner:

```
.home-top-box .banner{
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.home-top-box .banner img{
    width:100%;
}
```

Tried changing height to 100%, using min-height - those still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a repaint will occur regardless. Setting the height ahead of time will prevent content from reflowing once the image is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this so that the parent has an inner padding that matches the image aspect ratio. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIbtp.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/5C10I.png

```
.home-top-box .banner {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    /* width: 100%; */
    /* display: inline-block; */
    padding-bottom: 66.6%; /* (500 / 750) * 100 = 66.6% */
}
```

Comment: Michael, you answer works. Thanks so much! 

As i see inlined image height/width are not playing any role here.
Is it still better to have it as  <img src="mobile-main.jpg" width="750" height="500">
 Or should I simply use as  <img src="mobile-main.jpg" >
Usually it’s recommened to have height/width inlined, but not sure how is better for responsive images.

Comment: @MployBy I don't use inline height/width and just control it via css instead. CSS is far more flexible, and if you add inline attributes, you now have additional things to maintain and update if you change the widths.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the image aspect ratio, then you could recalculate your height using jQuery:

```
$.ready(function(){
    $("div.banner").height($("div.banner").width()/750*500);
});
```

You shold take in account some padding, margins and borders, or make them zero if possible.